# How to convert specified elements of the ndarray to the concrete type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science, numpy-ndarray

***I have to do it without using pandas or something else, just pure numpy***

I have a big `ndarray` of `numpy.str_` read from the CSV file, I'd like to convert every element of every **column** to the particular type. For instance, I know that in the 2nd column there will be an integer and I would like to convert all elements of the first column to `numpy.float`, every element of the 2nd column to `numpy.int` and so on, is there a way how to elegantly implement it?

+Is there a way how to specify what element should be converted to what type when I convert `list` to `ndarray` with `np.array()`, somehow to play with the dtype?

I tried to find something and found this https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#structured-arrays but I don't think that it is what I'm looking for. In case it is, could explain me how to use it in my case.

Appreciate your help.

Example:

I have `[['1', '1.6', 'hey']['2', '5', 'tr5']]`

How do I get something like

`array([1, 1.6, 'hey'][2, 5.0, 'tr5'])`

Comment: How did you load the data from the `csv`?  You can specify a compound `dtype` when using `genfromtxt`, or `dtype=None` to let it deduce the dtypes for you.

Comment: Since I have to read from zipped csv I use this code:

```zf.open() and then csv.reader()```
`genfromtxt` is the way?

Comment: `genfromtxt` accepts an opened file as argument (or anything that can feed it lines).  I have tried `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, structured arrays is what you need.

You have to pass the `dtype` argument as follow:

```
np.array(data, dtype=[(name1, type1), (name2, type2), ...])
```

Where data is a list of tuples with fields.

You have to convert the original array to that structure.

If you dont need the names just put empty str.

you also can put dtype argument as `dtype=np.dtype(type1, type2,...)`

Comment: `yy = [['1', '6.6'], ['2', '7.6']]
tt = np.array(yy, dtype=[('p1', np.int_), ('p2', np.float_)])
print(tt)`


Hmm.. I tried it^^ what do I do wrong here?


`tt = np.array(yy, dtype=[('p1', np.int_), ('p2', np.float_)])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6.6'
`

(Sorry, cannot format it)

Comment: `np.array([ ( '1', '6.6' ), ('2', '7.6') ], dtype=[('p1', np.int_), ('p2', np.float_)])`.  The data for a structured array needs to be a list of **tuples**.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj !